# Adding an ImageView at a random position in a LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, imageview

I want to add image views dynamically to a full screen linear layout. I have written some code but some image views are either partially or totally going outside the screen. Some times image views are well within the phone screen.

How can I ensure that they remain totally inside the screen.

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();

getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

final int widthArea = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
final int heightArea = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
final LinearLayout home = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llHome);

ImageView imgView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200);
imgView.setLayoutParams(lp);
imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_1);
imgView.setX(r.nextInt(widthArea));
imgView.setY(r.nextInt(heightArea));
home.addView(imgView);
```

Comment: Your question's title request "how to display at random position" yet your question seems to mean "it displays randomly yet I don't want that"

Comment: I want random positions but inside the screen. Nothing outside.

Answer (score 0):

You should take into account the dimension of the image itself. Settings X and Y place its starting point within the screen but it might leak on a side.

First, load your image as a `Drawable`, then include `drawable.getWidth()` (and maybe even height, that depends on your layout) to your *X* position.

```
imgView.setX(r.nextInt(widthArea - drawable.getWidth()) + drawable.getWidth());
```

Comment: I have tried this. but didn't get what i wanted. views are added to last as a result of addView() so after 4-5 images all other are added at very bottom of the screen and are hidden.

Comment: That only depends on your container. Setting random positions in a relative layout (for example) should work.